# Export json to xlsx in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to export my json to xlsx. I'm able to export it but, not getting the right format in excel file.

Here is my code :

```
downloadFile() {
 let  Obj =  {
    "data": [12,123],
    "date": ["2018-10-10","2018-02-10"]
  }
  const items = [];
  items['data'] = Obj.data;
  items['date'] = Obj.date;
  const header = Object.keys(items);
  let csv;
  header.map((data)=>{
  csv = this.items[data];
  });
  csv.unshift(header.join(','))
  let csvArray = csv.join('\r\n');
  var blob = new Blob([csvArray], { type: 'text/csv' })
  FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "filename" + ".xlsx");
}
```

O/p I'm getting : ["Data, Date","2018-10-10","2018-02-10"]

I'm not able to render date values in excel

Screenshot of my exported excel file : 
  [image]

Comment: What is the purpose of the functions `pageViewGraphData`?

Comment: I have done that with table which is easy

Comment: ["2018-10-10, 2018-02-10"]

Comment: What "format" (let's say, "table layout") are you expecting precisely ?

Comment: I just want data values in data col and date values in date col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like below. In order to have data in one column and date in one column you will have to structure the data in a way that when arranged in columns it appears as you want it. Below is a sample you can try to download this will work as expected. 
A simpler solution will be creating a hidden html table with the data with the similar structure as you want to export and then convert that to CSV.

```js
function downloadFile() {
  let Obj = {
    "data": [12, 123],
    "date": ["2018-10-10", "2018-02-10"]
  }
  const items = [];
  items[0] = Object.keys(Obj);
  items[1] = [Obj.data[0], Obj.date[0]];
  items[2] = [Obj.data[1], Obj.date[1]];
  let csvContent = '';
  items.forEach((rowArray) => {
    let row = rowArray.join(",");
    csvContent += row + "\r\n";
  });
  console.log(csvContent)
}

downloadFile();
```

Below is an example of how to download  HTML table to CSV. And as you are working with angular you can create a table from your data using '*ngFor'.

```js
function toCsv() {
  const csv = [];
  const rows = document.getElementById('table').querySelectorAll("tr");

  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let row = [];
    const cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
      row.push(cols[j].innerText);
    }
    csv.push(row.join(","));
  }
  console.log(csv.join('\r\n'));
}
```

```css
table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Geronimo</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Natalia</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>Spain</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Silvia</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>Russia</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="toCsv()">Export HTML table to CSV file</button>
```

Use Filesaver to downlad these CSV string to file.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: One more thing bro.. what if I have 'n' no. of values in data and date

Comment: For that try my other solution. create a html table with hidden class `display:none` then you will data structured as you want it in the csv. Then its use the table to export to CSV. Will add a sample code to the answer to do that.

Comment: Can you please give me an example ?

Comment: @KedarKulkarni check the update this way you can download a html table to a csv file.

Comment: Can't we do it typescript itself, without using table in html ?

Comment: Yes we can do it in typescript as well for its for you to decide you will have to then play with the data and structure it as required.. To me table one seems a bit easy..

Comment: Iterating given obj in table seems to be problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200893/discussion-between-manish-and-kedar-kulkarni).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const data = [
  [12, "2018-10-10"],
  [123, "city2", "more info"]
];
let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
data.forEach(function(rowArray) {
  let row = rowArray.join(",");
  csvContent += row + "\r\n";
});
```